# run python3 from virtualenv

Tags: django, python-3.x

I still can't finally understand how apache understands which version of python it should now run.

In virtualenv I install only python3.2 , then I put such code on wsgi wrapper:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/virtualenvs/simpleboard/bin/python

import os, sys, site

my_virtualenv_path = "/virtualenvs/simpleboard/lib/python3.2/site-packages/"
# Add it to your PYTHONPATH


sys.path.insert(0, my_virtualenv_path)
site.addsitedir(my_virtualenv_path)

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, '/www/django/simpleboard/simpleboard')
sys.path.insert(0, '/www/django/simpleboard')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "simpleboard.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

finally I add this tag in the head of my class code but apache still run 2.7

```
Exception Location:     /www/django/simpleboard/account/views.py in rescale, line 386
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    
['../..',
 '/www/django/simpleboard',
 '/www/django/simpleboard/simpleboard',
 '/www/django/simpleboard/simpleboard',
 '/virtualenvs/simpleboard/lib/python3.2/site-packages/',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']

Server time:    Wed, 11 Sep 2013 19:43:21 +0400
```

As you can see it runs 2.7 version and traceback errors because of it

Comment: Whichever python version shows up when you type "python" into your command line, is what will get used unless you specify behavior (like activate in your virtual environment). Also, make sure you used Python 3 to make your virtual environment or it will refer to Python 2.7

Comment: I am afraid of changing usr/bin/python to run python3 because I am not sure that it don't break all my server settings.

Comment: When I activate virtualenv he runs python3 as python  (simpleboard)root@simpleboard:/virtualenvs/simpleboard/bin# python
Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:11:55) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: My be I can configure virtualhost in apache settings or something else without changing of behavior of usr/bin/python?

Comment: Use gunicorn on nginx, it will save you a lot of sleepless nights.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the virtualenv support of uwsgi (http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnv). Adding "H /virtualenvs/simpleboard" to your uwsgi commmand in your uwsgi init script.